# Changes on Android 9 Pie creating SQLite database files on phone (?)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-version, android-9.0-pie

Im creating an app but when i start to create the database clases (sqlite) and it works , now the sqlite files are different in android 9, in anothers versions you go to /data/data/packageapp/databases and you found database.sqlite and database.sqlite-journal, now i found this and this files cant open on sqlite administrator or similars... But the databases works i dont know what happen, i want to create the last files

Check the photo

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV8hB.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Android 9 SQLite by default it now uses Write-Ahead Logging mode (WAL) instead of the journal mode due to it's potential for increased performance. Which is why you see the the **-shm** (Shared Memory file) and the **-wal** (Write Ahead Logging file) files.

[Temporary Files Used By SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html)

However, you should be able to open the actual database file (***yonuncafrases.sqlite***) elsewhere in tools that support opening SQLite Databases. [Compatibility WAL (Write-Ahead Logging) for Apps](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/compatibility-wal)

> i want to create the last files

If need be you can force using journal mode by using the SQLite disableWriteAheadLogging method, noting that this must be done outside a transaction, and then Journal Mode would be used and that the **-journal** file would then be created as necessary.

- I'd suggest overwriting the **[onConfigure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onConfigure(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase))** method and calling disableWriteAheadLogging in that overridden method. Alternatively you could use the [journal_mode pragma](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) (which I believe is what disableWriteAheadLogging does anyway)

You may wish to read [Write-Ahead Logging](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)